# When/How should I validate commands using the CQRS pattern

Tags: c#, .net

i have a question, how should i validate data input by a command? I thought about using a DTO, and after validating it, mapping it to the command. But I think this is the wrong approach. What would be the correct way?

Comment: Do you mean a `Command` as an `System.Windows.Input.ICommand`?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomennd `MediatR` and `FluentValidation` combination for that.

Take a look at this [article](https://code-maze.com/cqrs-mediatr-fluentvalidation/)